# \if@Latin undefined in bidi v20.0

Tags: packages, bidi, xepersian

From the `bidi` manual:

> `\if@Latin` inside any environment that uses Latin font is true and
>   inside any environment that uses RTL font is false.

I have `bidi` version 20.0 and a simple example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}
\begin{document}
This is typeset by \textsf{bidi} package, \bidiversion, \bididate.
\makeatletter
\if@Latin yes \else no \fi
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

doesn't compile and produce the error:

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.6 \if@Latin
> ```

Note that many commands depend on this boolean test, for example `\lr` from `xepersian` package. Another nor working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Amiri} 
\begin{document}
\lr{hello world}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think an output of `\listfiles` could be useful for comparison. (Also, you probably know this, but the example works on bidi v17.6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue is due to a change in name of test, refer to: https://github.com/vafa/bidi/blob/master/bidi.dtx

You can find `\newif\if@nonlatin` and not `\newif\if@Latin` and this change is not mentioned in the manual of `bidi` version 20.0, also packages that use this boolean test like `xepersian` did not do the necessary changes.

With bidi version 20.0 the MWE become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}
This is typeset by \textsf{bidi} package, \bidiversion, \bididate.
\makeatletter
\if@nonlatin no \else yes \fi
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Both `\if@Latin` (old boolean, now deleted) and `\if@nonlatin` booleans are internal and a user should not use them. Instead, use `\iflatin` and `\ifnonlatin` macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bidi}

\begin{document}
This is typeset by \textsf{bidi} package, \bidiversion, \bididate.

\iflatin{We are in latin mode}{We are not in latin mode}

\ifnonlatin{We are not in latin mode}{We are in latin mode}
\end{document}
```

> [image]